# Cell title from dictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table with 3 sections. I also have an array of dictionaries that I use for naming my cells, among other things. I want to populate my second section with items from my dictionary based on the favorite key.

This is what my dictionary looks like:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>favorite</key>
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>accessories.sku</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>favorite</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>accessoriesImage</string>
        <key>checkedState</key>
        <string>NO</string>
    </dict>
```

I've iterated through this dictionary before for other things and I know I need to do that again but I can't quite grasp it for this case.

```
static NSString *kTitleKey = @"title";
static NSString *kCheckedState  = @"checkedState";
static NSString *kFavorite = @"favorite";

for (id dict in myArray]) {
    if ([dict[kFavorite] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
       cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] valueForKey:kTitleKey];
    }
}
```

But of course **cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] valueForKey:kTitleKey]** isn't correct.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, you want to loop through all the dictionaries in your array, and create a cell for each dictionary that has "YES" as the value for the "favorite" key?  Then set the textLabel.text to the value for the "title" key?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are already matching your `dictionary[kFavorite]` then why you want to take it from `myArray`. you can code like this your loop,

```
for (id dict in myArray]) {
   if ([dict[kFavorite] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
      cell.textLabel.text = dict[kTitleKey];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter the array using NSPredicate, then drive the second section with the filtered array:

```
static NSString *kTitleKey = @"title";
static NSString *kCheckedState  = @"checkedState";
static NSString *kFavorite = @"favorite";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[c] %@", kFavorite, @"YES"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```